# SettingsProperty are not saved in the specified order, why?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

during runtime i save properties and each property name gets an incremented prefix:

- XXX_**00**_MySetting
- XXX_**01**_MyOtherSetting
- XXX_**02**_MyOtherOtherSetting

however the order should be the same as i applied to the add function of the SettingsPropertyCollection right?

But this is not the case everytime i open the user.config after
the properties are saved. They have been written to file in a completly different order..

Even when i do this it doesnt work (which i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30287011/8489062))

> `Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.OfType<SettingsProperty>().OrderBy(s => s.Name);`

this is how i set up the property:

```cs
SettingsProperty setting = new SettingsProperty(settingName);
                        setting.PropertyType = typeof(double);
                        setting.DefaultValue = column.ActualWidth;
                        setting.IsReadOnly = false;
                        setting.Provider = Settings.Default.Providers["LocalFileSettingsProvider"]; ;
                        setting.Attributes.Add(typeof(System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute), new System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute());
```

This is how i save the setting

```cs
Settings.Default.Properties.Add(setting);
Settings.Default[setting.Name] = someValue; // Off topic: this is how it actualy get written into user.config only adding the property to properties doesnt do anything. Maybe because this is how it get recognized as overwritten default value
```

I expect it to be written to user.config as specified

- XXX_**00**_MySetting
- XXX_**01**_MyOtherSetting
- XXX_**02**_MyOtherOtherSetting

not like

- XXX_**02**_MyOtherOtherSetting
- XXX_**00**_MySetting
- XXX_**01**_MyOtherSetting

Comment: Use Insert (with index zero) instead of Add.  Add put new data at end of list.  You want to put new item at beginning of the list.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the SettingsPropertyCollection doesn't provide an insert function. After a close look it gets clear why [.NET Doc SettingsPropertyCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.settingspropertycollection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

Comment: Why is the order relevant? Its just a file written and read by your application. Surely it works with any order?

Comment: Looking at the source of the Collection show that its a HashTable. Means it has no order you can really influence. That brings us back to the "why anyways" question.

Comment: You are using the wrong type object.  Settings object doesn't care about order.  You want a object the maintains an order.

Comment: @Ralf Yes it would work without sorting but its like a messy closet you will find the clothe you want but if its not sorted it will look ugly and you need more time to find it. Maybe its my autistic vein which wants that.

Comment: @jdweng i think you misunderstood something.

Comment: Then just think that its ordered by the property names hash. That is way faster then being ordered by the actual name.

Comment: @Ralf Well that is actually how it works now but that makes the user.config not better it will remain a messy place for visitors who are opening the file. ^^

Comment: Why do you want your users to edit a file? Wouldn't a GUI be much more convenient?

Comment: @BionicCode This file should never be opened by an user only and maybe only by developers. Why should i programm an GUI for user.configs which are depening on the user interactin with the programm. I mean the options are dynamically set by the users interaction and for my purpose it wouldn fit, i dont/cant use a options menu or something like that. I just wanted to do it clean thats why i would like to see them sorted.

Comment: I just thought you were worried about your users having to deal with an "unsorted" config file. This would make sense - only this. Those are just a set of key-value pairs. First time somebody is worried about a lexical sorted config file :) How about different sort criteria? You could sort by context or relevance. Both would be more meaningful to me than a lexical sorted file. I guess this should comfort you that what you believe is clean actually isn't. Clean is always evaluated by a common  standard. I doubt any developer considers a lexical structured file "clean", usually.

Comment: Additionally this file is intended to be accessed by a machine. Therefore it is a unstructured chaotically random set of data. It's like formatting binary file content. If this matters, you could de-/serialize your settings data models directly to JSON. It will give you the best of both worlds. It's  machine compatible while allows to be formatted for humans at the same time. Depending on the size of settings data you can ignore that a table based structure is faster.

Comment: The prefix "XXX" is the context and the numeric part 01 should make the order given in the code dependent on the initialization of the fix column. There would be no common standards if no one would set them ;) The json thing is not an option as it would make everything more complex, now user.config is handled automatically, consuming json would make it more time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments its not really possible to sort the order of the SettingsPropertyCollection since its using an hashtable.

Thank you guys for your replys.